# Google places search box without map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to implement a feature where people will be able to change their location. For that I want to use google places api. Now what I want is a search box and when someone inputs a town/place it will search google places and come up with results. Once location is choosen it will give me lat and lng of that place. Is that possible to do without the map?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Google Maps Places Autocomplete to get an accurate address, and then after you successfully get an address you can geocode it to get the lat and lng.

Like this:

```
function codeAddress(address) {
   geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
         alert(results[0].geometry.location); // This is the lat and lng
      } else {
         alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
  });
}
```

Check this working example: https://jsbin.com/pejagub/edit?html,js,output

I also inserted here the code snippet incase the jsbin is not working

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete, geocoder;

function initAutocomplete() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function codeAddress(address) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      // This is the lat and lng results[0].geometry.location
      alert(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  codeAddress(document.getElementById('autocomplete').value);
}
```

```css
#autocomplete {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" />
  </div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late. You may find your answer here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#video

```

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, {
  bounds: defaultBounds
});
```

```

No need for map object reference just pass the bounds.